# Is it technically possible to replace aging body part and live forever?

Tags: surgery, life-expectancy, internal-organs, stem-cells, organ-transplant

I heard that iPS cells can be used to make some human organs ([Takebe, et al. 2013](https://www.yokohama-cu.ac.jp/en/20130701-takebe-vascularized-and-functional-human-liver-from-an-ipsc-derived-organ-bud-transplant)).

If we make young organs using regenerative medical techniques and replace aging organs with them, can we live forever?

### References

Takebe, T., Sekine, K., Enomura, M., Koike, H., Kimura, M., Ogaeri, T., ... & Aoyama, S. (2013). Vascularized and functional human liver from an iPSC-derived organ bud transplant. *Nature*, 499(7459), 481. doi: [10.1038/nature12271](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature12271)

Comment: It's going to be hard to replace the brain, and that's the organ that spells the end for many people.

Comment: I have come across some interesting info about reverting aging on rats by transplanting pineal gland from old to young and vice-versa. https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?hl=pt-BR&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=pineal+gland+transplantation&oq=pineal+gland+tra#d=gs_qabs&p=&u=%23p%3Dw6tZwaRdD8UJ

Comment: You're asking a question which has no answer at the current level of science

Comment: I would argue this will never be possible because of vital organs brain, etc. that can't be feasible be replaced at all and definitely do degrade over time.